# Image uploader faster

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a multi image selector uploader the problem I am having is once selected images and click submit it takes ages to to the request is there any way of making it process faster??

Do not worry about database table and columns are there for testing reasons not made my full database yet just been testing 1st.

Thanks in advance.

```
   <?
session_start();
include('connect.php');
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }
$desired_dir="Uploads/";    
    $query="INSERT into Pictures (`id`,`Image1`,`Image2`,`Image3`) VALUES('','$desired_dir$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Everything works spot on just slow at uploading images and inserting into database.

Comment: How big is the file you're uploading? How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: Highest size is 858kb don't know what my connection speed is, everything else loads on click just the images uploader is slow once click submit.

Comment: define slow. 10 seconds, 10 minutes?

Comment: While I'm here does anyone know what I can put into that code so max images can be 3??

Comment: That sounds about right for most residential internet connections. Check your upload speed here http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: 6.72mbps download - 0.38mbps upload

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, the upload seems normal. You have a slower internet connection and will experience a slowdown when uploading files.

I also strongly recommend you look into [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Your current script is wide open to attack

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no multi threading upload of files to server. And the upload speed is limited with **server's download speed** and **user's upload speed** (which is much more slower then server's download speed). Unfortunately, it is not possible to make uploads faster by changing the code.